# (Python) Loading Excel dictionary data array is incorrect in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried insert Excel dictionary date to python dic with pandas,
but it faild to load correct array,

Here is my code.

```
import pandas

my_dic = pandas.read_excel('/Users/dnshin/Documents/pythonsubkoreanizedic.xlsx', index_col=0).to_dict()
print (my_dic)
```

And here is a capture,  Correct excel source
[image]

But when i finished load by pandas,
it print below array error
[image]

that capture show the korean words 'a - 어 ' is located incorrect place.

as see by dict type, below capture
[image]

So, How can i fix it to correct array?
please let me know somebody

Answer (score 0):

First you need to tell pandas that the sheet has no column headers by passing `headers=None` to `read_excel`, and then you can build your dictionary manually (`to_dict` won't help you here):

```
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/dnshin/Documents/pythonsubkoreanizedic.xlsx', header=None)
d = dict(zip(df[0].values, df[1].values))
```

This creates a dictionary with the left column as keys and right column as values.

Comment: Perfect answer, Thanks, i didn't know function 'zip'